# Real time count queries to Google Big query, will it perform relative to MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I have a tens of TBs of data on client profiles in Google Cloud storage. I run aggregation on it using Google Big Query from a c#.net windows service. Aggregations are not time critical so works great.

But now I want to direct count queries from a website to this dataset, so clients can estimate # of records in their filtered data. I realize querying TBs dataset while there is a web server waiting on the other end for result is not a good idea. So I have decided to create a statistical sample of it, like about 100K rows. 
As approximated results are ok with this use case.

My question is should I keep the sample data in a google big query table or bring it to a mysql db near to my web server and run queries there. Former seems like a more neat design buy I am concerned about performance. But with later I have support 2 dbms & haul data down to mysql?

Thanks.

Comment: What are your current execution times? Do you use the sampled db for anything else?

Comment: If the end user expects a latency below 5 or 10 seconds, I would personally store the data in a database other than BigQuery.

Comment: It really depends on a lot of factors, so this is pretty much impossible to answer in full here, but BigQuery, while fast, is made to handle BIG data, with emphasis on that and not speed. So if you really want responsiveness, another db might be in order. Also, BigQuery's not built to be consistent in how long queries are treated, so this may cause some surprise to your users. You could of course use a dashboard that gets cached and refreshed every hour to gain more responsiveness.